# Is "damage" an ergative verb?

Tags: verbs

Does "it damages w/o object" mean "it damages itself"?

For example:

> If you use your car too much it damages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To damage" is a transitive verb, and therefore it needs an object.

Therefore, this:

> If you use your car too much it **damages**.

is not OK. You can eventually rewrite it as:

> If you use your car too much it **gets damaged**.

or:

> Too much use **damages** your car.

where "your car" is the object of "damages".